# Internet Connection Speeds Slow, iOS 9 not downloading --- Newest Refurbished AirPort Time Capsule

Tags: airport, software-update, internet

First off, I'm using a *manufacturer* (Apple) refurbished AirPort Time Capsule, the newest model, which was delivered by UPS a few hours ago to my new house. I bought it directly from Apple.

The technician from Hughesnet, which is satellite internet, finished installing the equipment (satellite dish, modem, etc.) earlier today. A tech support rep promised me speeds of ***at least*** 9 mbps, with the max being 15. Yet, I'm never able to get more than 7 or 8, nothing close to the already-slow 15 expected or even the 9 that the tech support representative promised.

My problem is that regular webpages (such as Apple, Wikipedia, MLB) all load reasonably quickly, yet I am never able to download iOS 9. After a few minutes, iTunes on my MacBook Pro (mid-2009, running OS X 10.10.5 "Yosemite") will have about "1024.0 KB" downloaded, then the request will time out. The update doesn't seem to be downloading on my iPhone 5S, either, but it downloaded part way on a relative's Wi-Fi network earlier this week.

I've spent literally hours on the phone with Hughesnet's technical support and we were finally able to prove that the modem is working properly and that the problem must be the router.

The Airport Time Capsule has been updated to the latest software. Both the router and the modem have been power cycled multiple times.

Is there something more that I can do to troubleshoot my Airport Time Capsule? Could this just be a problem with Apple's software update servers?

**Update:**
I just ran another speed test using the Ookla Speedtest app and it's now showing a 20 mbps download speed, but the iOS 9 update still won't install.

[image]

Comment: Apple's servers might just be overloaded still. Can you download stuff from other sites without issues?

Comment: @patrix I think that that was the issue. I was finally able to finish the download last night, it just took it a while. Anyways, I think that everything is working correctly now, as the Xcode 7 update is downloading pretty quickly.

Comment: Same issue for me, download speed is about 2 days to go on both my devices - iphone 5 and ipad mini retina.

Comment: @user39710 My advice would be to restart your iDevices frequently and keep trying to install the updates, as eventually it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something more that I can do to troubleshoot my Airport Time Capsule?

Your OOKLA speed tests indicate that your AirPort is working correctly.

> Could this just be a problem with Apple's software update servers?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to download iOS 9 is download though you computer.  Connect your iPhone to your computer, open up iTunes (make sure you have the last version of iTunes), backup your iPhone and install iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with your connection. Since iOS 9 hit the market, iOS/app update are really slow, no matter of your connection speed.

There is solution, that I just googled. Log off App Store, switch iDevice off for a while, then log into App Store back. I haven't tried it yet.